# django xhtml2pdf not getting image

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to render html to pdf, it really works great ! only there is an issue and that is the template getting image:

I am using python `xhtml2pdf` library for pdf render

this is my method for render pdf:

```
def render_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return HttpResponse('Unable to process the request, We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))
```

and this is my `views.py` below:

```
def test_view(request):
    context = {
        'test': 'a test string'
    }
    return render_pdf('test.html', context)
```

and this my `test.html`

```
{% load static %}
<p>hello test </p>
 <img src="{% static 'ok.jpg' %}">
```

It gets image if i render with django default `render` method But the image not getting when i render for pdf.

I heard of this solution with `link_callback` method with this documatin: https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

I am not getting where to include this or how can i achive this.

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: You can render the image directly in the views. `img = settings.STATIC_URL + "/path/to/img"` and send it through context before rendering your pdf. You need to render the pdf with `template.render(Context(context))` and use it as a variable `<img src="{{img}}" >`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest modifying your html template, and use the absolute / relative path (directory path in your hard drive) of the image file instead of using {% static %} tag. static tag is only good for rendering the HTMl, but pisa cant read the image from that.

I have this code from a project that generates a PDF from html, and my images are done like this:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_ROOT }}/report/logo.png" >
```

where STATIC_ROOT is a variable passed from render context.

Comment: I passed, it dont works, i guess, i need to change something on setting file>

Comment: try hardcoding a path to an actual file in your drive

Comment: Yes, I tried with hardcoded: STATIC_ROOT = '/home/py/Desktop/weasprint/staticfiles'

Comment: is ok.jpg under staticfiles? or maybe staticfiles/img

Comment: NO, It is in staticfiles, not in any sub folrder

Comment: so your image in html should now be <img src="/home/py/Desktop/weasprint/staticfiles.ok.jpg">. xhtml2pdf should spit out any warnings / errors if it cant find the file

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/py/Desktop/weasprint/staticfiles/ok.jpg when i hit this url, it doesnt find the staticfiles

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me if it is still relevant.

My static folder is in my root directory.

{% load static %}

Comment: <img src="static/images/MicrocareLOGO.png" >

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).